# Django signals and User Auth

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm currently following Hacked Existence's Django tutorial a bit. I'm having trouble understanding the Django signals involved

```
    def create_User_callback(sender, instance, **kwargs):                   
        a, b = User.objects.get_or_create(user = instance)

    post_save.connect(create_User_callback, User)
```

I'm not quite sure the logic behind

```
     post_save.connect(create_User_callback, User)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a signal handler to work, you need to bind it to a signal. That is done using the signal's `connect` method. In your case, the signal is `post_save`.

`connect` is called with the name of the method and the model for which the method will be called. All models will emit `post_save`, so when you add `User` as the second argument to `connect`, it "filters" the signals so only the `post_save` signal that is emitted by the `User` model will trigger your method.

Think of it like tuning a radio to listen on a frequency.

Having said all that, this actual code seems a bit pointless. You are creating an object (or fetching one if it exists) of the same class that is emitting the signal; after any object has been saved.

Comment: Well the goal of this code is to able to authenticate users. Perhaps this should clear things up? I'm still learning Django at the moment. This all seems very confusing

http://pastebin.com/DvCDzSsV

Comment: For authentication, use the [built-in authentication framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/).

Comment: As a side-note: `connect` stores a __weak reference__ to the signal handler. It might get garbage-collected at some point rendering the handler gone if not referenced from persistent object like module.